# How do I programatically check if an Attribute Group exists in magento

Tags: php, magento

Is there a standard way to checking if an attribute group exists within an attribute set in Magento?

I've looked everywhere, but did not find anything beyond getting a list of all attribute groups, then looping through them.

Is there a better way to do it? Please advise.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, found the answer embedded on a page which describes how to add attribute sets. 
Here's the relevant information:

```
$model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_setup', 'core_setup');
$attributeSetId = $model->getAttributeSetId('catalog_product', 'Default');
$attributeGroupId = $model->getAttributeGroup('catalog_product', $attributeSetId, 'name of attribute group here');
```

Haven't heavily tested the code above, but it did what I needed it to do; I quickly moved on.